# Call EVP_Digest() or directly call MD4? Openssl - different timing

Tags: c, performance, openssl

I measured how many times I can call MD4 in 3 seconds. I used MD4 from Openssl. But noticed an interesting issue. When I called `MD4(array, size, digest);` directly, my app said that I could do 5438501 MD4's within 3 seconds. When I used `EVP_Digest(array, size, digest, NULL, EVP_md4(), NULL);` it said that it did 4787370 MD4's in 3 seconds.

So a direct call is faster than using EVP API? Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why `EVP_Digest` should be faster than the method it uses :-)

Using `EVP_Digest` you are delegating "him" (it) to use for you an hash algorithm. Clearly there is some overhead in this. Or perhaps you think that `EVP_Digest` could use some "magically faster" MD4 algorithm than the "default" MD4 algorithm?

From [md4/md5](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html) (emphasis added)

> Applications should use the **higher level** functions EVP_DigestInit(3) etc. instead of calling the hash functions directly.

And from [EVP_DigestInit](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html)

> The EVP digest routines are a **high level** interface to message digests.

Where high level == slower :-)

So why should you use the `EVP_Digest`? It's explained in the [same page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html) as before:

> The EVP interface to message digests should almost always be used in preference to the low level interfaces. This is because the code then becomes transparent to the digest used and much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, that was my point - when I use `EVP_Digest` - `there is some overhead in this`. So it's true, that `EVP_Digest` is because of it slowler than directly calling `MD4`, right? I don't think that there's a magic in it, no way :P So no matter what way I choose, I will always end up calling `MD4` (but with `EVP_Digest` not directly but with overhead, right?) :)

Comment: @nullpointer Yes. In OpenSSL there are low level algorithms (like MD4) and higher level interfaces that are able to connect to various similar low level algorithms (like EVP_Digest)

Comment: OK, now I understand. Cheers!